# Altarnate line on graph - AChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I need to add alternate line on linear chart like shown in the attached image. (Indicated by red arrow)

[image]

Is this possible?

How can I achieve this output?

Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide example ?

Comment: @DerGolem I think you misunderstood it, I have updated the image now have a look at it and let me know if it is possible or not.... Thanks

Comment: @DerGolem I can not set image because if I scroll graph upwards that lines also should move upwards.

Comment: @DerGolem I have modified the AChartEngine library to achieve this.

Comment: @DerGolem I can not use backaground image as I want that alternate lines to get scrolled vertically with the graph.